# How to update latest.civicrm.org?

Tags: upgrade, documentation, version

There's a file http://latest.civicrm.org/versions.json which isn't up to date - it's missing a few betas, but most notably, it's missing CiviCRM 4.4.14.  This is the source data for [CiviMonitor](https://github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.civimonitor), which uses it to check if a version is up-to-date.

Is this file generated by hand, or with code?  If by hand, is there a git repo I can submit a PR against?

Comment: BTW I have updated the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that latest.civicrm.org/versions.json is the canonical source for CiviCRM version information.

The file is quite new and the release-publishing script has not yet been updated to write to it (an [issue has been filed](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15762) for this), so at the moment it must be updated by hand.

I agree that the file should be under version control.

If anyone is available and interested in helping with either task, get in touch on [#civicrm](http://irc.civicrm.org) IRC channel, or by email to coleman at civicrm)